# Find the last digit of $\binom{2016}{21}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find the last digit of the binomial coefficient:
>   $$\binom{2016}{21}$$

I would start by factorial form:

$$\binom{2016}{21} = \frac{2016!}{21!(1995!)}$$

But that doesnt help much?

Comment: Hint: Try finding the largest power of 5 and 2 that divide it.

Comment: Notice that $ \frac{2016!}{1995!} = (2016)\cdots(1996)$. Further, notice that finding the first digit of ${2016\choose 21}$ amounts to finding ${2016 \choose 21}~(\mathrm{mod}~10)$.

Comment: @bashfuloctopus Of course, you mean the last digit.

Answer (score 4):

By [Lucas' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem) we have:
$$\binom{2016}{21}\equiv\binom{3}{4}\cdot\binom{1}{1}\equiv 0\pmod{5}\tag{1}$$
as well as:
$$ \binom{2016}{21}\equiv 0\pmod{2}\tag{2} $$
so the last digit of $\binom{2016}{21}$ is $\color{red}{0}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** We can rewrite the coefficient as
$$\frac{2016 \cdot 2015 \cdot \cdots \cdot 1997 \cdot 1996}{21 \cdot 20 \cdot \cdots \cdot 2 \cdot 1}.$$
How many trailing zeroes does the numerator have? The denominator?

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{2016!}{21!\cdot (1995)!}=\frac{1996\cdot\ldots\cdot2016}{1\cdot 2\cdot\ldots\cdot21}$$

Clearly $\;5^4\;$ divides the denominator, whereas in the numerator there are already $\;5^3\;$ for $\;2000\;$ alone, plus the power for $\;2005,\,2010\,\ldots\;$ Thus, $\;2\cdot5\;$ divides this number, so...

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $\frac{2016!}{1995!}=2016 \times 2015 \times \dots \times 1996$, where 3 of them have factor $5$, and $2000$ among the 3 has factor $5^3$, which means $\frac{2016!}{1995!}$ has five $0$'s at the last digits. Only 4 of $21!$ have factor $5$, and none of them have higher power of $5$, which means $21!$ has four $0$'s at the last digits.

(Number with $2^n$ as factors will always be greater than $5^n$, so counting $5$'s is enough.)

Answer (score 0):

The given number equals $\frac {1996 \cdot 1997 \cdots 2016} {21!}$ so the largest power of $10$ dividing it is $10^2 = 100$. Hence, the last two numbers are $00$.